# How to kill all alarmmanagers which are not being kept track of android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am not keeping track of which alarm managers are being set in the app and they also run after the app has been closed. How to I set a button in my app such that it kills all alarmmanagers running? Also, when will the android system kill the alarmmanager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All alarms are being kept truck by system. Because it needs to activate them at supposed time in future.

In order to cancel alarm you need to create the same pending intent which was used to set alarm. Same pending intent means it has same `requestCode` and same `intent` (without extras). After that you just call `.cancel()` method of alarm manager variable and pass to its parameters this intent.

Android OS deletes all set alarms when the phone shuts down. This means that when you boot your phone again you will not receive any alarm at their expected time.

Comment: Thanks; so creating an identical pending intent and canceling it will cancel all pending intents with the same requestcode and intent (but the extras don't have to match the actual intent's extras)?

Comment: There could be only one alarm with particular requestCode and pending intent. It is not possible to create two alarms with the same pending intent and requestCode. Second will cancel previous one or will update it or other behavior that you set as 4th parameter in your pending intent

Comment: It means that when you call cancel method and pass pending intent, the system will look for the alarm which has the same pending intent. There will be only one which matches it. Then this alarm will be canceled. Other previously set alarms will stay there.

Comment: @kmindspark Please consider accepting and upvoting my answer if you think it helped you.